# How to set a version to chart.yaml file in azure devops pipeline

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a .Net project includes **Chart.yaml**
I want to set a version in the file when running pipeline.

**Powershell**

```
$newversion = "v5.0.0-a"
$chartyaml = "Chart.yaml"

$yamlText = (Get-Content $chartyaml) 
$yamlText.replace('appVersion: .*','appVersion: $newversion')
$yamlText > $chartyaml
```

**Chart.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v2
appVersion: "v5.0.0-a"
description: A Helm chart for Kubernetes
name: application-api
version: "v5.0.0-a"
type: application
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A work around for your scenario is using PythonScript as below:

```
  def change_yaml_content(file_path, key, value):
  
      with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
  
          data = yaml.load(f, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
  
          data[key] = value
  
      with open(file_path, 'w') as f:
  
          yaml.dump(data, f)
  

  
  file_path = "YAML_Folder/Chart.yml"
  
  key = "appVersion"
  
  value = "1.0.0"
  
  
  
  change_yaml_content(file_path, key, value)
```

This script is for helping specify your appVersion, if you would like to specify another section, you can just change "appVersion" to specify another section.

Answer (score -1):

See a sample here - https://github.com/relizaio/rebom/blob/master/.github/workflows/github_actions.yml - line 283 and below.

Note, that the script is for GitHub Actions but you could use same idea for Azure DevOps.